# Google Optimize Test on SPA - Tag firing but test not showing

Tags: single-page-application, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

I hope you can help me.

I am trying to use Google Optimize with an SPA and am installing via Google Tag Manager.
I have followed the instructions, set up a datalayer which fires optimize.activate, so all good so far. I can see the optimize tag is firing, and the basic a/b test is configured to look for that datalayer (rather than pageload).
I also have a cookie consent popup on the page.

My issue is that if i load the site and allow cookies, the optimize tag fires as expected but the a/b test does not trigger and there's no _gaexp cookie. If i hit refresh i can see both the a/b test change and the optimize cookie.

What do i need to do to make the optimize test fire once someone has allowed cookies?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire optimize.activate after allowed cookies

Comment: Yes, optimize.activate fires after cookies are enabled. However optimize still doesn't pick this up without a full page refresh. I assumed that if this fires (which it does multiple times) optimize would pick this up and it'd just work

Comment: Any success in this? I'm trying to change a text into an Angular 9 app with google optimize. But it only works if the change is the first page to load. If it's on a 4th step of a form, I can't change =/

Comment: Have you tried in debug mode @ToneMalone? In this mode, you can see if the experiment starts, sometimes it starts the experiment twice, but the second time it tells you that it cannot be activated because it has already been activated before